# How to read FormData into Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, model-binding

I seek your help for a Web API extension which could support model binding from Form Data say, `FormDataAttribute` (hypothetical), or guidance from community on how to achieve it.

```
public class NammaApiController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult PostFDFromBody([FromBody]FD reqBody)
    {

        return Ok();
    }

    public IHttpActionResult PostFDFromFormData([FromFormData]FD reqBody)
    {

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Default Web API model binder works only for raw input, unfortunately.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently did a sort a like scenario, on your controller, use this method signature in your controller class

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("search")]
 public IHttpActionResult Search(System.Net.Http.Formatting.FormDataCollection search)
```

Then create an extension method on the FormDataCollection class to convert this FormDataCollection to a NameValueCollection, easier later.

```
public static NameValueCollection Convert(this FormDataCollection formDataCollection)
{
    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> pairs = formDataCollection.GetEnumerator();

    NameValueCollection collection = new NameValueCollection();

    while (pairs.MoveNext())
    {
        KeyValuePair<string, string> pair = pairs.Current;
        collection.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }

    return collection;
}
```

Then you have a `NameValueCollection`, and then in a class, create a constructor like:

```
public SearchQuery(NameValueCollection formdata) : base(formdata)
{
    FirstName = formdata["FirstName"];    
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried passing two keys in order to test it, however only one could be submitted, that also value retrieved on API was strange : ------`WebKitFormBoundaryYeK7GSBvc3k6tR1n\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name`

Comment: Is this code suitable for `x-www-form-urlencoded` not Form-Data?

Comment: in my code I was using postdata and not x-www-form-urlencoded ,but  you could check this link: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Aug/16/Mapping-UrlEncoded-POST-Values-in-ASPNET-Web-API and I think it will be possible somehow

Comment: thanks for the pointers will take forward. Consider doing +1 to quest ;-)